# Float a paragraph next to another paragraph in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the below snippet, there is a block of large text and a block of small text. How would I go about making the small text "hug" the big text?

```html
<p style="float: left;margin: 0px;font-size: 300%;max-width: 15rem;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec scelerisque pharetra velit, sed pretium mauris consectetur quis. Donec ut dolor id ipsum bibendum egestas id eu est. Fusce egestas hendrerit neque et laoreet. Etiam tempus, sem in consectetur gravida, sapien enim accumsan tortor, non molestie ipsum ex vel nulla. Vivamus a nisi commodo, hendrerit augue vel, pulvinar sapien. Morbi lobortis, velit feugiat gravida venenatis, lorem magna fringilla lacus, ac posuere velit mi eget ex. Nam iaculis pellentesque ullamcorper. Vestibulum condimentum efficitur urna eget semper. Nam velit velit, vulputate at justo sed, sollicitudin efficitur sapien.
<br>
Curabitur egestas orci et vulputate mattis. Nunc vehicula semper porta. Pellentesque mattis magna felis, vitae rutrum quam condimentum vel. Morbi hendrerit suscipit purus. Proin ullamcorper nec est a iaculis. Nullam et lacus odio. Morbi ut tortor feugiat, volutpat nisl maximus, aliquam libero.
<br>
Fusce iaculis enim elit, in commodo nisl feugiat at. Integer mauris mauris, finibus quis tempus et, euismod et lorem. Morbi finibus urna orci, ac vehicula enim luctus at. Maecenas blandit posuere nisi eget commodo. Maecenas quis turpis porttitor, fringilla nisi non, interdum diam. Nunc ipsum enim, lobortis sit amet velit elementum, maximus pretium erat. Ut sollicitudin urna quis felis molestie suscipit. Fusce ultrices eleifend velit, eu aliquam libero pharetra id. Nulla suscipit in purus sit amet tincidunt.
<br>
Suspendisse nec porttitor erat. Nam nulla ex, mattis rhoncus semper ut, malesuada quis mauris. Cras fringilla accumsan ligula scelerisque pharetra. Vivamus luctus, magna a rhoncus posuere, nisi neque fringilla risus, id maximus elit sapien at libero. Morbi lectus nulla, hendrerit at tortor sed, aliquam dapibus elit. Aenean sodales, neque in convallis rhoncus, nisl neque commodo nisi, a bibendum justo mi at libero. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Etiam commodo, est a ornare sagittis, massa odio porttitor enim, in dignissim ipsum massa sed diam. Nunc scelerisque lorem nec lacus mattis auctor. In eu arcu id dui convallis ultricies. Maecenas viverra condimentum velit. Integer posuere ipsum ut ante aliquet, euismod bibendum augue gravida. Sed ultrices aliquam faucibus. Aenean vel mauris ac tellus euismod fringilla. Aliquam lobortis molestie ipsum, at imperdiet leo scelerisque id.
</p>
```

I am willing to be as hacky as possible.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do

Comment: Kindly explain or illustrate the meaning of "hug".

Comment: If you want to show two paragraphs in same row then you can make a div with class="row" and then in this div you can add more div with column size and add your paragraphs in these div.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean? Does this help?

```
<style>
.float_txt {
position: fixed;
margin: 0px;
font-size: 300%;
max-width: 15rem; 
}

.main_cnt {
padding-left: 240px;
} 
</style>

<p class="float_txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.</p>

<p class="main_cnt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec scelerisque pharetra velit, sed pretium mauris consectetur quis. Donec ut dolor id ipsum bibendum egestas id eu est. Fusce egestas hendrerit neque et laoreet. Etiam tempus, sem in consectetur gravida, sapien enim accumsan tortor, non molestie ipsum ex vel nulla. Vivamus a nisi commodo, hendrerit augue vel, pulvinar sapien. Morbi lobortis, velit feugiat gravida venenatis, lorem magna fringilla lacus, ac posuere velit mi eget ex. Nam iaculis pellentesque ullamcorper. Vestibulum condimentum efficitur urna eget semper. Nam velit velit, vulputate at justo sed, sollicitudin efficitur sapien.
<br>
Curabitur egestas orci et vulputate mattis. Nunc vehicula semper porta. Pellentesque mattis magna felis, vitae rutrum quam condimentum vel. Morbi hendrerit suscipit purus. Proin ullamcorper nec est a iaculis. Nullam et lacus odio. Morbi ut tortor feugiat, volutpat nisl maximus, aliquam libero.
<br>
Fusce iaculis enim elit, in commodo nisl feugiat at. Integer mauris mauris, finibus quis tempus et, euismod et lorem. Morbi finibus urna orci, ac vehicula enim luctus at. Maecenas blandit posuere nisi eget commodo. Maecenas quis turpis porttitor, fringilla nisi non, interdum diam. Nunc ipsum enim, lobortis sit amet velit elementum, maximus pretium erat. Ut sollicitudin urna quis felis molestie suscipit. Fusce ultrices eleifend velit, eu aliquam libero pharetra id. Nulla suscipit in purus sit amet tincidunt.
<br>
Suspendisse nec porttitor erat. Nam nulla ex, mattis rhoncus semper ut, malesuada quis mauris. Cras fringilla accumsan ligula scelerisque pharetra. Vivamus luctus, magna a rhoncus posuere, nisi neque fringilla risus, id maximus elit sapien at libero. Morbi lectus nulla, hendrerit at tortor sed, aliquam dapibus elit. Aenean sodales, neque in convallis rhoncus, nisl neque commodo nisi, a bibendum justo mi at libero. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Etiam commodo, est a ornare sagittis, massa odio porttitor enim, in dignissim ipsum massa sed diam. Nunc scelerisque lorem nec lacus mattis auctor. In eu arcu id dui convallis ultricies. Maecenas viverra condimentum velit. Integer posuere ipsum ut ante aliquet, euismod bibendum augue gravida. Sed ultrices aliquam faucibus. Aenean vel mauris ac tellus euismod fringilla. Aliquam lobortis molestie ipsum, at imperdiet leo scelerisque id.
</p>

<!-- Spacing to show effect -->
<div style="height:500px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, lets have two paragraphs

```
<p>Paragraph 1, on the left</p>
<p>Paragraph 2, on the right</p>
```

The issue is, they are not next to each other yet.

By default, HTML makes the paragraph as wide as the screen. We do not want that. We want that paragraph to only be part of screen and the other paragraph to fill the other side of the screen.

We can do this by giving both paragraphs a specific width. If we give each paragraph 50% of the width of the window, we have room to put them together.

```
<p style="width: 50%">Paragraph 1, on the left</p>
<p style="width: 50%">Paragraph 2, on the right</p>
```

But that doesn't work yet. Why? HTML automatically puts elements under one another..unless we tell them otherwise. Every element `defaultly floats to the left`...So lets just tell paragraph 2 to `float: right;`.

```
<p style="width: 50%">Paragraph 1, on the left</p>
<p style="width: 50%; float: right;">Paragraph 2, on the right</p>
```

Problem solved. If you want paragraph 1 to fill more of the screen, change the widths to add to `100%`. `p1`'s width could be `80%` and `p2`'s width could be `20%` for example.

If this is solution works for you, please mark this as the accepted answer. Thank you.